# mat2cell to divide 3D image into blocks

Tags: matlab, 4d

I have a 4D image of size `60 x 80 x 12 x 350`, i.e. it is a 3D image where each voxel has a time series (of 350).

Now I want to use `mat2cell` to divide the 3D image into cubes of dimension `k*k*k`. Each voxel in the cube is a vector of size 350 (the time series).

I think I could do it with `mat2cell` but I don't know how exactly. Each cell should contain in the end a 3D block of the image where each voxel of the block is a vector of size 350.

Comment: What is `k` here? Also, can you explain clearly what the resulting cell should contain?

Comment: what happens it `L x W x C`(C=channels) is not evenly divisible by `k x k x k`? for instance using your dimenstions ` 60 x 80 x 12 x 350` and  `k=10` you can make voxels for `60 x 80 x 10` but what happens for the last 2 channels?

Comment: @andrew I took care of that in my answer and did a cut off final cell. I think it's cleaner than padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 4D matrix is called `M`. You need to have vectors whose elements sum to `size(M, i)` where `i = 1:4`. Assuming `k` has some value, I tried both 4 (because it's a common factor of the sizes you specified) and 3 (because it's not).

```
k = 3;
MPrime = mat2cell(M, ...
    [k*ones(1, floor(size(M,1)/k)), mod(size(M,1), k)], ...
    [k*ones(1, floor(size(M,2)/k)), mod(size(M,2), k)], ...
    [k*ones(1, floor(size(M,3)/k)), mod(size(M,3), k)], ...
    ones(1, size(M,4)));
```